# Point stability error in one dimension dynamical systems

Tags: sympy, analytics, symbolic-math

I am studying two different systems in python, looking for fixed points and their stability. Managed to solve completely for the first one, but applying the same method raises an error i dont know how to deal with in the second one.

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Zero which has no callable exp method
```

I don't really know how to handle it, since when i make an exception for this error I simply skip the answers and i am certain there are possible answers and analytically i see no reasons for them not to exist

```py
from sympy import *  
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

r = symbols('r', real=True)
x = symbols('x', real =True)
#first one
fx =r*x+((x**3)/(1+x**2)) # DEf. both fet and right side in EQ
fps = solve(fx, x)
print(f"The fixed points are: {fps}")


dfx = lambdify(x,fx.diff(x))

for fp in fps:
    stable_interval = solve_univariate_inequality(dfx(fp)<0, r, domain=Reals, relational=False)
    unstable_interval = solve_univariate_inequality(dfx(fp)>0, r, domain=Reals,  relational=False)
    #print(type(stable_interval))
    print(f"{fp} is stable when {stable_interval}")
    #print(type(unstable))
    print(f"{fp} is unstable when {unstable_interval}")
```

```py
fx2 = r*x+( x* E**x)
fps2 = solve(fx2, x)
print(f"The fixed points are: {fps}")

dfx2 = lambdify(x,fx2.diff(x))

for fp in fps2:
    stable_interval = solve_univariate_inequality(dfx2(fp)<0, r, domain=Reals, relational=False)
    unstable_interval = solve_univariate_inequality(dfx2(fp)>0, r, domain=Reals,  relational=False)
    #print(type(stable_interval))
    print(f"{fp} is stable when {stable_interval}")
    #print(type(unstable))
    print(f"{fp} is unstable when {unstable_interval}")
```

I expected the method i created to be applyable to the second system fx2 but i dont understand the logic behind why this doesnt remain true.

Comment: Don't mix star imports. Also there's no need to use numpy or `lambdify` here.

Answer (score 0):

Oscar mentioned in the comment to not mix star imports: that's correct! Let's understand what you are doing:

1. with `from sympy import *` you are importing everything from sympy, like `cos`, `sin`, ...
2. with `from numpy import *` you are importing everything from numpy, like `cos`, `sin`, ... However, many things share the same names as sympy, so you are effectively overriding the previous import. Result: a complete mess that will surely raise errors down the road, as your namespace now contains names pointing to numpy and others pointing to sympy. Numpy and Sympy doesn't work well together!

Best ways to resolve the situation. Keep things separated, like this:

```py
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
```

Or import everything only from one module:

```py
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
```

Now, to your actual problem. With this command:

```py
dfx2 = lambdify(x,fx2.diff(x))
# where fx2.diff(x) results in:
# r + x*exp(x) + exp(x)
```

`lambdify` created a numerical function that will be evaluated by Numpy: note that this function contains an exponential, which is a Numpy exponential. Then, you evaluated this function with `dfx2(fp)`, where `fp` is a symbolic object (meaning, it is a Sympy object). As mentioned before, Numpy and Sympy do not work well together.

Easiest solution: asks `lambdify` to create a function that will be evaluated by Sympy:

```py
dfx2 = lambdify(x, fx2.diff(x), "sympy")
```

Now, everything works as expected.

Alternatively, you don't use `lambdify`. Instead, you substitute your values into the symbolic expression. For example:

```py
dfx2 = fx2.diff(x)
for fp in fps2:
    stable_interval = solve_univariate_inequality(dfx2.subs(x, fp)<0, r, domain=Reals, relational=False)
    unstable_interval = solve_univariate_inequality(dfx2.subs(x, fp)>0, r, domain=Reals,  relational=False)
    #print(type(stable_interval))
    print(f"{fp} is stable when {stable_interval}")
    #print(type(unstable))
    print(f"{fp} is unstable when {unstable_interval}")
```